# Create One-to-One relationship based on PK of both tables

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5

I'm really new to Entity Framework (currently using EF5) and vs2012 and am having difficulty trying to figure something out.

I have an .edmx that was generated from my database.  It has two tables in it: `Item` and `3rdPartyItem`.  In short, the `Item` table is the main table for all the company items while the `3rdPartyItem` table is a table that is used to hold additional attributes for items.  This `3rdPartyItem` table was created by an outside company and is used with their software for the company, so I can't mess with either table.  What I'm trying to do is show a list of Items in a grid but I need to show a combination of all the fields for both tables.  In vs2012, if I create a relationship and make it 'zero-to-one' (because for each record in the Item table, there doesn't necessarily have to be one in the 3rdPartyItem table), vs complains about not being mapped correctly.  When I set the mapping, it then complains that there's multiple relationships.  I did some research and found that you can't create a relationship with 2 primary keys, so I was thinking that was the problem.  But how can I change the .edmx so that in code, I can access Items and 3rdPartyItem like so:

```
var items = dbContext.Items;
items.3rdPartyItem.SomeField <--field from 3rdPartyItem table.
```

not too sure if it's even possible, but it would be very, very helpful if so.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is table-per-type (TPT) mapping inheritance.  You can view an MSDN walkthrough here (although you'd want your base type to be instantiable):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618293.aspx